# Is assigning to a sub-level of an undefined array an error?

Tags: php, syntax

Looking at this code:

```
$arr = array();
$arr['a']['b']['c'] = 'd';
```

My feeling is that I should be getting an error, "Undefined index: a". But I'm not. Is my php misconfigured, or is this acceptable practice?

My php version is 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.3

Comment: thanks for sharing; earlier I always separate this initializations. :)

Answer (score 2):

It has never been an error.  By assigning a value to `$arr['a']['b']['c']` you are creating `$arr['a']`, `$arr['a']['b']` and `$arr['a']['b']['c']` so are not accessing undefined indexes. No error even without `$arr = array();`.

It is perfectly acceptable.